# Import data for data analysis

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner in python and i just started learning. Your help would be appreciated. I have been having trouble importing an excel file.
Each time i try to import an excel file i see this reply:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-61fd8ec00fb3> in <module>
      1 #Lecture d'un fichier texte
----> 2 tips = pandas.read_csv("donnees/tips.csv",
      3                        header = 0, sep = ",")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    608     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    609 
--> 610     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    611 
    612
```

Comment: the error looks quite clear - you haven't got the correct path to read the file, are you on windows or mac? also it looks like your importing a `csv` not an `excel` ? you need `pd.read_excel` for reading an excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is - invalid path 
Cause - maybe your IDE / jupyter notebook are not in same directory... where you kept your file.

Instead of "donnees/tips.csv"   give complete path like d:folder/filename.csv  it will work.

Alternatively  copy the folder donnnees in the same folder where jupyter notebook save its data. ( C:users/yourusername)